# Use add_filter inside another function

Tags: filters

I generated metabox for woocommerce gallery images. And i put there youtube video id.

```
add_filter('attachment_fields_to_edit', 'video_link', 10, 2);
function video_link($fields, $post) {
    $meta             = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'videolink_id', true);
    $fields['videolink_id'] = array(
        'label'        => 'Youtube ID',
        'input'        => 'text',
        'value'        => $meta,
        'show_in_edit' => true,
    );

    return $fields;
}
```

Ana i am saving meta fields:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_save-attachment-compat', 'video_link_kaydet', 0, 1);
function video_link_kaydet() {
    $post_id = $_POST['id'];
    $meta    = $_POST['attachments'][$post_id]['videolink_id'];
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'videolink_id', $meta);

    clean_post_cache($post_id);
}
```

And i get youtube thumbnail and save it to my media library.

```
add_action('edit_attachment', 'video_link_yukle', 1);
function video_link_yukle($post_id) {
    $videolink_id = isset($_POST['attachments'][$post_id]['videolink_id']) ? $_POST['attachments'][$post_id]['videolink_id'] : false;
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'videolink_id', $videolink_id);

    $url = 'https://img.youtube.com/vi/' . $videolink_id . '/maxresdefault.jpg';

    rg_insert_attachment_from_url($url, $post_id); // it is my function. it works.

    add_filter('wp_generate_attachment_metadata','water_mark', 10, 2); // but this filter doesn't work.
    return;
}
```

Finalyy i saved thumbnail to media library but now. i want to create watermark for thumbnail. So i must use add_filter for my **water_mark** function. But this add_filter doesn't work inside function.

Comment: Try `apply_filters` instead of `add_filter`. See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/apply_filters/

Comment: tried apply_filters. but it now work. by the way add_filter works outside function.

Comment: You shouldn't need to add a filter within another function. Why can't you hook water_mark outside the function?